# Send message to client by userId by SignalR | .NET 6, Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, authentication, signalr

My signalR hub works good. I configure it with simple example.

StartUp.cs

```
services.AddSignalR();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>  
{  
  endpoints.MapHub<BroadcastHub>("/notify");  
});
```

Interface IHubClient

```
public interface IHubClient
{
 Task BroadcastMessage();

 Task BroadcastToConnection(string data, string connectionId);

 Task BroadcastToUser(string data);
}
```

BroadcastHub.cs

```
public class BroadcastHub  : Hub<IHubClient>
{
  public ClaimsPrincipal GetConnectionId() => Context.ConnectionId;
}
```

My angular side

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
  .withUrl(`${environment.apiUrl}/` + 'notify')
  .build();

this.connection
.start()
.then(function () {
})
.then(() => this.getConnectionId())
.catch(function (err) {
  return console.error(err.toString());
});

this.connection.on("BroadcastToUser", (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
}

 getConnectionId = () => {
 this.connection.invoke('getconnectionid').then(
   (data) => {
     console.log(data);
      this.connectionId = data;
     }
 ); 
 }
```

I can easy send message by connectionId through swagger by this way and it works good

```
    [HttpGet("signalr/{id}")]
    public async Task<string> Signalr(string id)
    {
        await _hubContext.Clients.Client(id).BroadcastToUser("test");
        return "message send to: " + id;
    }
```

But I want to send by userId and use this method - `UserId` I get from context

```
await _hubContext.Clients.User(UserId).BroadcastToUser("test");
```

But I don't see any result. As I read on code-mase [in this example](https://code-maze.com/how-to-send-client-specific-messages-using-signalr/) I need `to authenticate users and set the NameIdentifier claim in ClaimsPrincipal`

I use Auth web api in my .NET app. My atribute `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` works good. I dont understand how I can send message by userId